# How does the instanceof operator work in the context of downcasting in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the purpose of using the instanceof operator as a way to properly downcast an object in java. I really hope someone can help. Below is more code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
            Dog k = new Dog();
            Animal v = new Dog();
            if (v instanceof Dog){
                k = (Dog)v;

            k.getAnimalName(); // displays Parent Animal
            k.getDogName(); // displays Dog
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
    public void getDogName(){
        System.out.println("Dog");
    }
}

public class Animal{
    public void getAnimalName(){
        System.out.println("Parent Animal");
    }
}
```

1. Confused about how v is an instance of type Dog. Can someone please explain this?
2. Confused about what was displayed in the method calls (referring to k.getAnimalName() and k.getDogName). Is the reason behind why k could call both methods is because the type of k is a subclass of Animal?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! It might be a surprise to you, but your question is off-topic here. We deal with computer *science* questions, not programming questions. Please see our [help on topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Also [posted on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975161/how-does-the-instanceof-operator-work-in-the-context-of-downcasting-in-java). Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, you may flag to request migration.

Answer (score 1):

new Dog() returns a reference to a Dog object.

Animal v = new Dog () creates a Dog object, and assigns a reference to the variable v. At this point the compiler forgets what kind of object v is a reference to (it is a reference to an Animal or a subclass), but the reference *is* a reference to a Dog object.

v instanceof Dog checks what the object really is. You could have assigned a reference to a Cat object, but you *did* assign the result of new Dog(), so v is actually a Dog object and v instanceof Dog returns true.

(Dog) v would fail if v wasn't really a Dog object, but it is a Dog object (even though it is only declared as an Animal), so the assignment is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining this clearly :)

Comment: Is it correct to say that the variable v contains the reference to a Dog object AND the variable type for v is an Animal? I want to make sure that I am using the correct language. 

Also, what is the point of doing the casting of (Dog)v in the first place if we know that v is a Dog object prior to that line being called? (I'm referring to the line k = (Dog)v).